# What are the Perl techniques to detach just a portion of code to run independently?

Tags: perl, process, fork

I'm not involved in close-to-OS programming techniques, but as I know, when it comes to doing something in parallel in Perl the weapon of choice is `fork` and probably some useful modules built upon it. The doc page for `fork` says:

```
Does a fork(2) system call to create a new process running the same program at the same point.
```

As a consequence, having a big application that consumes a lot of memory and calling `fork` for a small task means there will be 2 big perl processes, and the second will waste resources just to do some simple work.

So, the question is: what to do (or how to use `fork`, if it's the only method) in order to have a detached portion of code running independently and **consuming just the resources it needs**?

Just a very simpel example:

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my @big_array = ( 1 .. 2000000 );  # at least 80 MB memory
    sleep 10;  # to have time to inspect easely the memory usage

    fork();
    sleep 10;  # to have time to inspect easely the memory usage
```

and the child process consumes 80+ MB too.

To be clear: it's not important to communicate to this *detached* code or to use its result somehow, just to be possible to say "*hey, run for me this simple task in the background and let me continue my heavy work meanwhile ... and don't waste my resources!*" when running a heavy perl application.

Comment: A child process will inherit all its parent's attributes.  There is no real way to get around that with forking I don't think.

Comment: Using `fork` is not mandatory. Any technique would be acceptable, even calling `system`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fork()` to `exec()` is your bunny here.  You `fork()` to create a new process (which is a fairly cheap operation, see below), then `exec()` to replace the big `perl` you've got running with something smaller.  This looks like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @ary = (1 .. 10_000_000);

if (my $pid = fork()) {
    # parent
    say "Forked $pid from $$; sleeping";
    sleep 1_000;
} else {
    # child
    exec('perl -e sleep 1_000');
}
```

(`@ary` was just used to fill up the original process' memory a bit.)

I said that `fork()`ing was relatively cheap, even though it does copy the entire original process.  These statements are not in conflict; the guys who designed `fork` noticed this same problem.  The copy is lazy, that is, only the bits that are actually changed are copied.

If you find you want the processes to talk to each other, you'll start getting into the more complex domain of IPC, about which a number of books have been written.

Comment: Wont it copy the memory for a very short period of time before calling `exec()` and then free the memory after the child terminates? and after all, if everything  converges to calling system/exec, then it's not even required to use fork :) .. OK, for `exec` it's required, but `system('... &');` seems to do the job well

Comment: @ArtM As stated, it's a lazy copy.  And `system('... &')` *is* `fork()` followed by `exec()`, with a shell stuck in the middle just for grins and a bit more fragility to boot.  More than one way to do it, there is; my way better I like.

Comment: On Linux every process with PID>1 is created via a fork (initially of init). For example, if you run something in your terminal, bash (or whatever) will fork to execute it. Copy-on-write semantics ensure that this is efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Your forked process is not actually using 80MB of resident memory. A large portion of that memory will be **shared** - 'borrowed' from the parent process until either the parent or child writes to it, at which point **copy-on-write** semantics will cause the memory to actually be copied.

If you want to drop that baggage completely, run `exec` in your fork. That will replace the child Perl process with a different executable, thus freeing the memory. It's also perfect if you don't need to communicate anything back to the parent.

Comment: Not sure if lexical variables are *shared*. I get these values under the RES/SHR columns for `ps` while both processes are running: 48m/1776 and 46m/156 (1M array elements).

Comment: sorry, it should be `top` instead of `ps` in the above comment

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to fork just a subset of your process's footprint, so the usual workarounds come down to:

1. `fork` before you run memory intensive code in the parent process
2. start a separate process with `system` or `open HANDLE,'|-',...`. Of course this new process won't inherit any data from its parent, so you will need to pass data to this child somehow.

Answer (score 1):

`fork()` as implemented on most operating systems is nicely efficient. It commonly uses a technique called copy-on-write, to mean that pages are initially shared until one or other process writes to them. Also a lot of your process memory is going to be readonly mapped files anyway.

Just because one process uses 80MB before `fork()` doesn't mean that afterwards the two will use 160. To start with it will be only a tiny fraction more than 80MB, until each process starts dirtying more pages.

Comment: I think it should be *until at least one process starts dirtying ...* or smth logically equivalent to this. Well, this `my @big = (1 .. 1000000)` is just a simple generic example code, it could be smth more complex and outspread over the entire codespace. And thanks for your intervention.